# How to update SceneBuilder GUI when change different object in simulaton program?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I am programming simulator app in Java. There are 3 different classes. Some changes in those classes must change TextField in GUI (SceneBuilder made). Button click in gui, must change objects in classes. I made GUI with `SceneBuilder`, I know how to use Controller class.
Is there any way to use controller class for `FXML` in object class to chage text in TextField? Something like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (0 != 1) {
        if (!stack.isEmpty())
            controls.settfAI("INFECTED"); //controls is FXML controller // settfAI is id of text field
        try {
            sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            CCLogger.cclogger(Watchman.class.getName(), Level.INFO, e);
        }   
    }
}
```

Second question, when I click button, can I program change of object in control class? Something like this:

```
@FXML
Button btnOne; //btnOne is id in SceneBuilder file
//...
// AmbulanceCar ambulanceCar=new AmbulanceCar();
public void clicked() {
    ambulanceCar.go(); // send ambulance car in some location 
}
```

My program has a lot of buttons and 3 TextField which must change state of simulator.

UPDATE:
I have city and moving persons. When person is infected, Watchman must see in TextField person position. I have fxml with buttons and textfields. I know that Watchman class must have Controler from fxml. I get Controler with

```
        Parent watchBtns = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ControlGUI.fxml"));
    URL contronLinkUrl=Paths.get("/ControlGUI.fxml").toUri().toURL();
    FXMLLoader loader=FXMLLoader.load(contronLinkUrl);
```

After that, I send Controler to Watchman class with

```
city.getWatchman().setControler(loader.getController());
```

In Watchman class I try to edit TextField with this code:

```
    public void setControler(ControlerControlGUI controlGUI)
{
    controlerControlGUI=controlGUI;
    System.out.println("Controler set!");
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    System.out.println("Watchman started!");
    while(0!=1)
    {
        try {
        if(!stack.isEmpty())
            { 
              controlerControlGUI.settfAI("INFECTED");
            }

            sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            CCLogger.cclogger(Watchman.class.getName(), Level.INFO, e);
        }   
    }
}
```

Now I got error

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to class javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader (javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane is in module javafx.graphics of loader 'app'; javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader is in module javafx.fxml of loader 'app')

UPDATE, if answer bellow is complicated for you...
In controller class, you can put objects which you will control. In my case this is something like this:

```
Person infectedPerson;
Ambulance ambulance;

//call in main function
public void setInfectedInfo(Person person,Ambulance amb)
{
    infectedPerson=person;
    ambulance=amb;
}
```

In other class I put this code to set same controller for fxml and class which will use them both

```
Stack<Alarm> stack= new Stack<>();
Vector<Ambulance> ambulances=new Vector<>();
ControlerControlGUI controlerControlGUI;

public void setControler(ControlerControlGUI controlGUI)
{
    controlerControlGUI=controlGUI;
}
```

In main class you can put:

```
    FXMLLoader loader=new 
       FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ControlGUI.fxml"));
    Parent watchBtns=loader.load();
    city.getWatchman().setControler(loader.getController());
    watchBtns.setLayoutX(840);
    watchBtns.setLayoutY(100);
    groupCity.getChildren().add(watchBtns);
```

I will try to explain last code part. First you make FXMLLoader with fxml file which have defined controller. Then you load it. (if you dont call load() this will not work). After that, yout must call getController to have same controller in your function and you can call controller funtions from outside to control your GUI part.

Comment: Look at some tutorials for the `Animation` API. [Here](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835) is a good one. [Here](https://carlfx.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/javafx-2-gametutorial-part-2/) is another good one.

Comment: 1. Yes, you need to pass the controller instance to your Object that should control it. But, if you want to change the text, you can bind the `TextField`'s `textProperty` to a [String Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/StringProperty.html) and change the String. 2. I didn't really understand your question. I think some more code to replicate would help.

Comment: @JulianBroudy I made changes that you suggest and get another error

Comment: I don't quite understand your code yet, 1 thing I can tell you is you cannot manipulate the GUI through threads that aren't JavaFX's main thread. For exactly this purpose, there are the [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) classes. As to your goal, I will post an example for you in a bit, I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: Please take a look at the posted answer and mark it an answer if it helped. If you are still having trouble, please edit your question to include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can further assist you. Right now there is too much unneeded details and too few necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can bind an `Object`'s text to a `Label` or a `TextField` to manipulate the GUI by manipulating the object and the other way around.

Note that this answer focuses on your question but does not provide you with a copy and paste solution. For that, I pushed the entire project (including the pom.xml) to a [repo on my GitHub](https://github.com/JulianBroudy/bind-object-to-gui) in case you want to clone it and play around.

I used a modular project with [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), you can find various ways to set up your environment [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

**App:** (main class)

```
package com.broudy;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**Watchman:**

```
package com.broudy;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Watchman {

  private StringProperty manipulatedText;

  public Watchman() {
    this.manipulatedText = new SimpleStringProperty("howdy!");
  }

  public String getManipulatedText() {
    return manipulatedText.get();
  }

  public StringProperty manipulatedTextProperty() {
    return manipulatedText;
  }

  public void setManipulatedText(String manipulatedText) {
    this.manipulatedText.set(manipulatedText);
  }
  
}
```

**PrimaryController:**

```
package com.broudy;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class PrimaryController {

  @FXML
  private Label manipulatedLBL;

  @FXML
  private Button primaryButton;

  @FXML
  private TextField manipulatedTF;

  @FXML
  private Button manipulateWatchmanBTN;

  private int i = 0;

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    List<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();
    texts.add("Hey! It works... Click again...");
    texts.add("Again...");
    texts.add("And again...");
    texts.add("Wohooo");
    texts.add("Yipeeeeeee!");
    texts.add("Notice: ...");
    texts.add("The text is changed in Watchman class but these change as well...");

    Watchman watchman = new Watchman();
    manipulatedTF.textProperty().bind(watchman.manipulatedTextProperty());
    manipulatedLBL.textProperty().bind(watchman.manipulatedTextProperty());

    //    This is another acceptable way of assigning actions to buttons, etc.
    manipulateWatchmanBTN.setOnAction(click -> {
      watchman.setManipulatedText(texts.get(i++));
      // This is just to reset the text
      if (i >= texts.size()) {
        i = 0;
      }
    });
  }
  
  @FXML
  private void switchToSecondary() throws IOException {
    App.setRoot("secondary");
  }
}
```

**Brief Explanation:**

The `PrimaryController` creates an instance of `Watchman` and binds its `textProperty` (`manipulatedText`) to the `TextField`'s and `Label`'s `textProperty`.

Note, the binding here is unidirectional which means only the `manipulatedText` affects the `TextField` and `Label` and not the other way around. To accomplish that you can use `bindBidirectional`.

Now, clicking `manipulateWatchmanBTN` only changes the text of the `Watchman`'s `manipulatedText` - **This was an answer to your second question**. Because we bound our GUI to it, the GUI elements we created using SceneBuilder also change - **and this is an answer to your first question**.

Feel free to tweak it to your specific needs.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. You helped me in some parts. I found one more way, I will update my question for others